# A GeoTIFF heightmap from SRTM embeds vertical planes along lat/lon grids in its 3D representation

Tags: dem, geotiff-tiff, blendergis

I've downloaded an SRTM GeoTIFF from Open Topography and converted it into the grayscale image before I imported it into Blender to improve the quality. It is apparent that vertical planes are cutting through the heightmap at places where I guess the lat/lon grid runs. It must have been there from the first in the GeoTIFF and probably be stood out through the enhancement procedure. How can I remove them without having to paint the lines or planes with a brush?

[image: heightmap seen from bottom]

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a link to this particular DEM? It's possible that the GeoTIFF was stitched together from tiles but the alignment was slightly out, leaving no-data along grid lines (looks like a value of 0). It's possible to 'fill' no-data gaps like this in QGIS, but it would help to see the exact raster. Also, are you using 'non colour data' to do the displacement?

Comment: I just found that it was because I didn't turn off the grid in MicroDEM before I exported the result. Thank you for your comment though, Steven! Have a great day!